# How to make a query that returns rows if deadline is two weeks / one month / two months from today, etc

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a spreadsheet that contains several columns with project information. I want to modify:

```
=QUERY( 'Compilation'!A2:L; " select A, B, F, I, L order by A" ; 0 )
```

so it returns values in L that fall within a specific date range. The data ranges are located in specific cells — in this case P1 and P2.

I need to repeat the operation for different date ranges.

PS. Note that in P1 the cell contains the formula `=today()` and P2 `= P1+14`.

Comment: Please share a doc with us.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the P1 and P2 cells mentioned are in the same sheet as the query, please try:

```
=QUERY(Compilation!A2:L," select A, B, F, I, L where L>date '"&TEXT(P1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and L < date '"&TEXT(P2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' order by A desc", 0)
```

If you wish the P1 and P2 dates included in any selection, add `=` between the angle brackets and `date`.

I have changed the sort order to avoid blank rows at the top.